# C array initialization via macro

Tags: c, arrays, macros

Question's Background:
`void dash(int *n, char c)` is to draw characters c separated by '+'.
Parameter `n` is an array of ints, e.g. {1, 3, 2} and '-' for `c` should give "+-+---+--+", which works fine.
To use dash I do `{int f={1, 3, 2}; dash(f, '-');}`, which makes the construct copy&pastable.

The question itself:
To avoid copy&pasting I wanted to do `#define F(X, Y) {int f=X; dash(f, Y);}`,
resulting in a nicely usable `F({1, 3, 2}, '-')`.
Unfortunately the compiler complains about F getting 4 (array's length + 1) arguments instead of 2.
So how can you give `{1, 3, 2}` as parameter to a macro?

Comment: It's not clear how `dash` determines how many elements are in the array.  Are there always 3?

Comment: I've implemented it to stop at the last Element, which has to be 0. But that wasn't important for the question itself, so i left it out here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Variadic macros are a feature of C99.

```
#define F(Y,...) dash((int[]){__VA_ARGS__},Y)
```

> So how can you give {1, 3, 2} as
>   parameter to a macro?

```
F('-',1,3,2);
```

Comment: I think it should be
#define F(Y, ...) dash((int []){__VA_ARGS__}, Y}

Note the (int []) cast and the missing semicolon.

Comment: I personally like that answer best. I'll do it this way or with varargs in dash. THX everyone!

Answer (score 4):

Here is my version:

```
#include <stdio.h> 

void dash(int len, int *n, char c){
  int i;
  printf("dash( %i, {", len );
  for( i=0; i<len-1; i++ )
    printf(" %i,", n[i] );
  printf(" %i }, '%c')\n", n[i], c );
}

#define NOPAREN(...) __VA_ARGS__ 
#define F1(arr,char)  { int f[]={NOPAREN arr}; dash(sizeof(f)/sizeof(f[0]),f,char); } 

#define F2(char,...)  { int f[]=__VA_ARGS__;   dash(sizeof(f)/sizeof(f[0]),f,char); } 

int main(void){
  F1( (1,3,2), '-' );
  F2( '-', {4,6,5} );
}
```

Result:

```
dash( 3, { 1, 3, 2 }, '-')
dash( 3, { 4, 6, 5 }, '-')
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to use a macro to set up and make these calls, I'd probably consider changing the interface to `dash()` to use varargs:

```
#include <stdarg.h>

void dash( char c, ...)
{
    // ...
}


int main() {
    dash( '+', 1, 3, 2, -1);   // note: negative number indicates 
                               //   the end of the list of numbers
    return 0;
}
```

Using varargs isn't the best thing in the world (they're difficult to use and aren't typesafe), but I think it would be better than the macro concoction you're trying to gen up.

Also, remember that even if you stick with your current interface for `dash()` and come up with a macro that does what you want, you still need to have a way to indicate the end of the sequence of numbers to be passed into `dash()`. Otherwise there's no way for dash to know when it has reached the end of the array.  You have several choices:

- use a sentinel value, such as 0, -1, or any negative number (like in the vararg example above)
- pass the number of elements in the array as another argument
- set the size of the array as a part of `dash()`'s interface.  In your example, `dash()` might require that an array of 3 ints be passed in. No more, no less (actually more would be OK - they just wouldn't be used). If you did this, fixing your macro would be much easier, but I suspect it's not how you want dash to behave.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `{ 1, 3, 2 }` as an argument to a macro if you define `{ 1, 3, 2 }` as another macro

```
#define PARAMS { 1, 3, 2 }
F(PARAMS, '-')
#undef PARAMS
```

Unfortunately, there seems to be no direct way to do literally what you ask, i.e. pass specifically `{ 1, 3, 2 }` in this specific form. It might be worth switching to alternative methods, including the C99-specific ones suggested in other answers.

Comment: not practical but creative, I didn't think of this one